Simulate/Translate CDCL resolution proof to PCR proof
It's easy to get a proof certificate from a CDCL style sat solver, e.g., CVC5 can generate a proof certificate for an unsat formula. I want to translate (or simulate) that proof to an algebraic proof system. A practical reason I want to ask this because CDCL resolution proof is easy to obtain but I don't know if there is general PCR proof certifacte generation tool. I have several questions regarding this:

Is there a procedure or an algorithm to simulate resolution proof to PCR proof in general?
My understanding is that searching a same unsat formula's proof is harder in PCR, is it worth to try to search that proof first in PCR if I want to use PCR instead resolution proof system.
Is there any sat solver using algebraic proof system?

Any pointer is appreciated. An example is shown below and this is only one step simulation.

1: Proof Complexity and SAT Solving, Chapter 7 in Handbook of Satisfiability, Sam Buss and Jakob Nordström.
Update i:
For q3, it seems that https://polybori.sourceforge.net/index.html, polybori is a relevant tool.
